# I got different results in windows and Linux! C++ code

Tags: c++

I got some error regarding this problem!
When I compile this in Windows IDE such as Code blocks there shows me garbage values but whenever I compile this in Atom in Linux I got perfect result!

So, what is the problem occurring here?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void getmat(int m, int n)
{
  int p[m][n];
  for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
      cin>>p[i][j];
    }
  }
}
void display(int m, int n)
{
  int p[m][n];
  for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
      cout<<p[i][j]<<"   ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
  }
}

int main()
{
  int a,b;
  cin>>a>>b;
  getmat(a,b);
  display(a,b);
}
```

### Expected output: if I input: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9

Comment: `p` in `getmat` and `p` in `display` are two entirely independent arrays. You're printing uninitialized memory.

Comment: Do note that `int p[m][n];` is illegal in standard C++ as `n` and `m` need to be compile time constants.  If you need a run time sized array use a `std::vector`.  To stop the code from compiling make sure you use `-pedantic-errors` in your compiler options for gcc.

Comment: @Shafiun Miraz Variable length arrays is not a standard feature of C++.

Comment: In main, add the following statement between the two function calls: `cout << "Undefined behavior\n";`

Answer (score 1):

`int p[m][n];` is not legal C++. Because in C++ array dimensions must be *compile time constants*. When they are not it is called a *variable length array* (VLA). VLAs are legal in C, but they are not legal in C++.

Even ignoring that issue, the array in `getmat` is not the same as the array in `display` even though they have the same name.. They are two different arrays. So there is no expectation that entering values into one array would change the values of the other array. It only 'works' in Atom because you got unlucky and you were fooled into thinking something meaningful was happening. The truth is that your code prints uninitialised values and so you could see anything.

Comment: this code also works in Visual studio and subline text also in linux! :D

Comment: int p[m][n] is a facility now in g++ (latest version). It works!! Maybe they added this facility for Java programmers

Comment: Can you please also provide the outputs?

Comment: @ShafiunMiraz Visual Studio Code and Sublime Text are editors, not compilers. Your code is still not correct.

Comment: @ShafiunMiraz It doesn't matter if 'it works' in any compiler you care to mention. That's just bad luck. As I said the output of your program is not specified by the C++ language, so you can't complain if some compilers give you different results from what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some functionality added by code blocks or visual studio but your code should never work as you intended.

The `p[m][n]` that you initialized gets out of scope as soon as you get out of the `getmat(a,b)` method. When the `display(a,b)` method is called it initializes a completely new `p[m][n]`. This new matrix can contain any garbage value.

Code blocks or visual studio might have an internal functionality which allows them to use the values from a previous same sized matrix instead of using garbage values. This is just my hypothesis. you would have to look in their internal code to see why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is described in other answers. One possible solution is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void getmat(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& p)
{
  for(auto & row : p)
  {
    for(auto & cell : row)
    {
      std::cin >> cell;
    }
  }
}

void display(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& p)
{
  for(const auto & row : p)
  {
    for(const auto & cell : row)
    {
      std::cout << cell << "   ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
  }
}

int main()
{
  int a,b;
  std::cin >> a >> b;
  auto p = std::vector<std::vector<int>>(a, std::vector<int>(b));
  getmat(p);
  display(p);
}
```

Use a vector instead of c-style array. Pass the vector as reference to the function. Use range based for loops to iterate over the vector.